# How call php function using Ajax from Twig template

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twig

I took over an app built on Twig 3 template, Bootstrap 3 framework. My knowledge is minimal. I have to extend its functionality: use Ajax to load data from the controller in PHP, when the user changes the tab-pane. No Symfony, so as I understand no routing, no 'path'. I read so many topics but didn't find an answer.

My controller, which renders twig page:

```
<?php

namespace Controller;

use Entity\App\Message;
use Entity\User\Observer;
use Entity\User\Team;


class ObserverController extends Controller
{
//some other functions

//render 'druzyna.htm.twig'
public function druzynaAction()
    {
        if(!isset($_GET['team']))
        {
            header("Location:app.php");
            die();
        }
        if (isset($_GET['year'])) {
            $year=$_GET['year'];
          }
        else {
            $year=2022;
        }

        $repo = $this->getRepository('User\Team');
        $t = $repo->byId(intval($_GET['team']));
        if(!$t)
        {
            header("Location:app.php");
            die();
        }

        $repo = $this->getRepository('Sighting');
        $teamsightings = $repo->TeamSightings($year, $t->getId());
        $TeamObservationsStats = $repo->TeamObservationsStats($year, $t->getId());
        $secretary = $t->getSecretary();
        $secretary_id = $secretary->getID();

        return $this->render('druzyna.htm.twig', array('team' => $t, 'secretary_id' =>   $secretary_id, 'teamsightings' => $teamsightings, 'year' => $year, 'TeamObservationsStats' => $TeamObservationsStats));
    }

       //load data via Ajax
       public function druzyna_gatunki() {
            //parameters
            $year = $_POST['year']; 
            $secretary = $_POST['secretary'];

            //all the sql and PDO code, which is correct
            echo json_encode($gatunki);
       }
```

In my druzyna.htm.twig file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
          $("a[href='#tab2']").one('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
              $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '???',
                data: ({year: {{ year }}, secretary: {{ secretary_id }}}),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (gatunki) {
                      //sth
                   }
          });
     });
</script>
```

How do I call the controller PHP file that rendered this twig page? Another problem would be t point-specific function in this PHP file, which should be impossible... (?). Should I create a new PHP file, just for this purpose, to load data to be sent via ajax? I tried it and was able to create a unique, separate PHP file, outside the twig structure. And call it from jquery, using a relative path. This solution works, but I have to create separate DB connections in PHP and would like to avoid that.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: Bootstrap 3 (I only inherited this project, it was made quite a while ago)

Comment: Do you have a some kind of entry point, like a front controller?? if not, you need instanciate your controller and call a functions inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Francisco pointed me in a right direction. Somehow I was only thinking about specific php files.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'app.php?m_id=16',
  data: ({
    year: {{ year }},
    secretary: {{ secretary_id }}
  }),
  dataType: 'json',
})
```

In AppKernel.php I added:

```php
case 16:
  $c = new Controller\ObserverController($this, DB_PREFIX);
  $m = "druzyna_gatunki";
  break;
```

Then in ObserverController

```php
public function druzyna_gatunkiAction() {
  //przekazywany parametr 'rok' i 'secretary'
  $year = $_POST['year'];
  $secretary = $_POST['secretary'];

  $repo = $this->getRepository('Sighting');
  $druzynagatunki = $repo->druzyna_gatunki($year, $secretary);
  echo json_encode($druzynagatunki);
}
```

Which gets data from `SightingRepository`.

Now I have another problem, it takes 18 seconds to get data. The same query takes 6s using `HeidiSQL`. But I guess I would have to post separate question to solve this problem.

Comment: You should look a symfony doc about front controller pattern as example; I think it help you a lot. The idea is on parse a url path and extract the script that your front controller must map.